# TS1056 - Accessors only available ... tsc not picking up tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, visual-studio-code

For code examples, scroll below. First section contains the `TypeScript`, second one the `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`. Using tsc (v2.1.6).

**The question I have** is how can I detect if typescript is picking up my tsconfig.json, see [github repo](https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/typescript-fundamentals/tree/master/003-ClassesAndInterface) where I'm runningot the issue: https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/typescript-fundamentals/tree/master/003-ClassesAndInterface.

When compiling commandline on with tsc - I get the error `src/index.ts(17,9): error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.` - but in tsconfig I made sure it is targetting ES5 or up... I don't see what's going wrong/or what I am overlooking here.

**TypeScript index.ts**

```
class Engine {
    constructor(public horsePower: number,
        public engineType: string) {
    }
}
class Car {
    // Fields
    private _engine: Engine;
    // Constructor(s)
    constructor(engine: Engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    // Properties
    get engine(): Engine { return this._engine; }
    set engine(value: Engine) {
        if (value == undefined) throw 'Supply an Engine!';
        this._engine = value;
    }
    // Functions
    start() { return `Started ${this.engine}.`; }
    stop() { return `Stopped ${this.engine}.`; }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "app"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "classesandinterfaces",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run tsc && node app/index.js",
    "tsc": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.json",
    "tscver": "tsc --version"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you have `"target": "es5"` inside the compilerOptions in the tsconfig?

Comment: Omg, I overlooked that, I'll try it out today @MattBierner - thanks already!